# How to solve Codeigniter validation problem with YYYY/MM/DD date format

Tags: regex, forms, codeigniter, validation

In the codeigniter framework, I,m trying send a date (Jalali Date) like this :

```
/* html */
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" value="1400/05/29" />
/* php */
/* validation lib */
$this->load->library('form_validation');
/* validation rules */
$this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Start Date', 'trim|required|exact_length[10]|regex_match[/^([0-9]{4})\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))$/]');
```

But it neither works nor returns an error, while it works when I remove the Regex validation. Below method works fine and returns true :

```
<?= (bool) preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))$/', '1400/05/29'); ?>
```

Could it be because of the "|" mark? And if yes, how should it be resolved?

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I used callback_function and It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date','StartDate','callback_checkDateFormat');

function checkDateFormat($date) {

if (preg_match("/[0-31]{2}/[0-12]{2}/[0-9]{4}/", $date)) {

if(checkdate(substr($date, 3, 2), substr($date, 0, 2), substr($date, 6, 4)))
  return true;
else
  return false;
} else {
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Use CallBack Function in your controller